# Convert Curl command with WAV file to Unity web request

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, curl

Currently trying to convert a curl command to Unity Web request

Curl Command:

```
 curl -H “x-app-key:APP_KEY_HERE“ /
   -F " file=@AudioFile.wav" /
   -F "user_token=USER_TOKEN_HERE" /
   -F "category=orange" /
   https://api.soapboxlabs.com/v1/speech/verification
```

And the code I've attempted:

```
   private string url = "https://api.soapboxlabs.com/v1/speech/verification";

 private string apiKey = "123456789";

 void Start()
 {
     StartCoroutine(MakeSoapboxRequest());
 }

 IEnumerator MakeSoapboxRequest()

 {
     List<IMultipartFormSection> form = new List<IMultipartFormSection> {
             new MultipartFormFileSection("file", "Assets\\Pilot1\\Audio\\soapbox_test.wav"),
             new MultipartFormDataSection("user_token", "aaa1234567"),
             new MultipartFormDataSection("category", "orange")
         };

     UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
     request.SetRequestHeader("x-app-key", apiKey);

     
     yield return request.SendWebRequest();


     if(request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
     {
         Debug.LogError(request.error);
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.Log("No soapbox error");
         Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
     }
 }
```

Keep getting an error HTTP/1.1.400 Bad request

As you can see I've tried and commented out, WWW form as well. Is it something to do with me sending the wav file? I've tried looking into sending it as bytes but was left confused. The API I'm sending it to only takes wav files. It returns a JSON file. I'm just using the downloadHandler.text as a test.

Any help would be appreciated. I haven't used CURL before and it's my first time trying Unity Web Requests.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the overload you are using for the file is [`MultiPartFormFileSection(string data, string fileName)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection-ctor.html)

and states

> **data**: Contents of the file to upload.
> **fileName**: Name of the file uploaded by this form section.

So what happens here is: You are trying to upload "file" as the file content in an **anonymous** file section.

---

I think you should rather get the actual `byte[]` and rather use the overload `MultipartFormFileSection(string name, byte[] data, string fileName, string contentType)`

> **name**  Name of this form section.
> **data**  Raw contents of the file to upload.
> **fileName**  Name of the file uploaded by this form section.
> **contentType**   The value for this section's Content-Type header.

e
e.g. like

```
// Of course you would probably do these async before running the routine to avoid freeze
string yourFilePath;
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(yourFilePath);

new MultipartFormFileSection("file", bytes, "soapbox_test.wav", "application/octet-stream")
```

---

**Finally note:**

While a path like your given `Assets\Pilot1\Audio\soapbox_test.wav` might or might not work in the Unity Editor it will definitely fail in a build application!

You should either put your file into the [`StreamingAssets` folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) and access it via

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "fileName.extension");
```

or use the [`PersistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) (you would of course have to make sure your file is stored there first)

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "fileName.extension");
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you so much! I had a feeling I needed to get the bytes from it but wasn't sure. Hadn't used streaming assests before so would never have found that out. Thank you!